# How to use Eclipse Remote Java Application with tomcat running on port 8080

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

**My goal:**

- I want to launch Remote Java Application within Eclipse to debug a web app on a tomcat server.
- The tomcat server is running on port 8080
- The jpda is using default value, so, the dt_socket is 8000

**Error messages:**

If my *Remote Java Application* is set to connect to localhost:8080 (tomcat port) :

```
Failed to connect to remote VM
com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException
```

If my *Remote Java Application* is set to connect to lcoalhost:8000 (dt_socketport) :

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

**Traces**

[image]

My tomcat server running on 8080.  I started the server with `jpda start` argument, using default options `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`.  The following are the starting traces :

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.4.8.
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1407 ms
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
nov. 17, 2021 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Adacel\integ\MSVC14.1.x86.debug\lexix_verbyx\3rdParty\tomcat\webapps\DM_WebApp.war
```

As you can see, the debug port is 8000 and the server port is 8080.

**What I tried:**

I thought that I should change my %JPDA_ADDRESS% value to 8080, but this doesn't work, the server complain that the port 8080 is already in use and the server cannot start.

So, my question is, how do I Remote Debug my web app that is runnning on tomcat?  It looks so simple, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thx

Comment: Your screenshot shows you trying to connect to the server port, 8080.

Comment: @nitind I tried with 8000, I got this message `Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect`

Comment: Is the JVM you're using to run Tomcat allowed to have incoming connections?

Comment: @nitind How can I do that?  I thought that doing `catalina.bat jpda start` using default values was enough?

Comment: It would be a firewall setting or prompt.